# Como abrir um arquivo do servidor com javascript?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho este código que abre um arquivo local, mas eu gostaria de abrir um arquivo do servidor sem precisar do input.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" onchange="run(this.files[0]);">
```

Javascript:

```
function run(file) {
    xyz.loadRomFromFile(file, function(result) {
        if (result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < runCommands.length; ++i) {
                runCommands[i]();
            }
            runCommands = [];
            xyz.runStable();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Amigo, não entendi bem a sua pergunta, mas pelo que entendi, realmente você não pode abrir um arquivo do servidor com `JS` porque ele é `Client-Side` você pode mandar uma requisição para  uma linguagem `Server-Side` e pegar o retorno e trabalhar com ele

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer é uma chamada assíncrona para o servidor. Por exemplo, para ler um arquivo `html` que está no servidor, você pode fazer assim:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        // codigo
        document.getElementById('conteudoDoMeuArquivo').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
}

xhr.open('GET', 'caminho/para/meu/arquivo.html', true);
xhr.send();
```

Caso esteja utiliando a biblioteca jQuery, fica um pouco mais fácil =):

```
$.get('caminho/para/meu/arquivo.html', function(data) {
    // codigo
    $('#conteudoDoMeuArquivo').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

É possível, mas não é elementar.

Como já foi citado, JS roda no cliente, então você deve fazer um serviço que receba o nome do arquivo que você quer abrir e que retorne seu conteúdo. Esse serviço pode ser REST ou pode ser um script server side, tipo PHP, ASP, Node.js ou Servlet Java. Enfim.

Depois disso você deve consumir esse serviço usando o http-request.